# Angle between two lines in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

In Ahlfors’ Complex Analysis he defines a line to be of the form z=a+bt where t runs through all real values. He then identifies its direction with arg(b), which certainly makes sense. However, he then defines the angle between z=a+bt and $z=a’+b’t$ to be $\arg(b’/b)$, clearly it depends on the order in which the likes are named. If $z=a’+b’t$ is “to the left” of $z=a+bt$ in the upper half plane, this definition makes sense since $\arg(b’/b)=\arg(b’)-\arg(b)$. However, I can’t seem to understand why this is true for the other two angles since $\arg(b/b’)=-\arg(b’/b)$. Visually, it seems to make more sense for the other two(complimentary?) angles to be $\arg(-b/b’)$. Where does my misconception lie?

Comment: The other angles are gotten by subtracting from $\pi$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you, I was able to get that and wasn’t sure if it abided by the definition.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Follow up question: In the chapter on conformal mappings, Ahlfors asserts that the angle between direct tangents to the arc z(t) and w(t)=f(z(t)) is arg(w’(t)) - arg(z’(t)). This seems to make sense if the lines are situated as I stated above, with the tangent to w(t) “to the right” of the tangent to z(t). So why does this assertion make sense if the tangents aren’t situated in such a way?

Comment: I am a little confused about what "to the right" means.  The tangents are intersecting straight lines.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The argument of the tangent to w(t) is less than the argument of the tangent to z(t) is what I meant by “to the right.” I am asking why the angle between those tangents is arg(w’(t))-arg(z’(t)). It makes sense when arg(w’(t))>arg(z’(t)).

Comment: I am not familiar with Ahlfors book and I am puzzled why this is important.